# Why does my Azure HTTP trigger function return more data than my specified output model?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have a simple Azure HTTP trigger function that is declared as follows

```
 [FunctionName("ProductQueries")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [Consumes("application/json")]
        public static async Task<ActionResult<JObject>> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
        }
```

The function works as expected and is triggered and I am able to access the data sent in and so on.

The problem is with the output of the function, I have specified an output as follows:

```
 return new OkObjectResult(new
            {
                Status = "kalle",
                Error = "nisse",
                Result = JArray.FromObject(doc)
            });
```

But in fact the function returns this:

```
{
    "result": {
        "value": {
            "status": "kalle",
            "error": "nisse",
            "result": [
....
```

I dont know where the top level result and value objects come from and I dont want them, I want my output to be what I specified as follows

```
{
    "status" : "kalle",
    "Error" : "nisse",
    "result" : [......]
}
```

Where to those extra levels come from? and how do I get rid of them to get the output I specified?

Comment: Because the "doc" in your code is a json array, so when you use JArray to format it, it will show as the first result you provided.

Comment: Really? How can I get rid of it I tried all sorts of things like JObject and so on but nothing works

Comment: The doc is actually a cosmosdb document to be fair

Comment: Is `OkObjectResult` being returned by child method (invoked from `Run`) and later the result of child method is further wrapped in `Run` method while returning?

Comment: @user1672994 there are no child methods the entire function is only 20 lines or so it’s a cosmosDB query that I capture in doc variable that’s all

Comment: So may I know what you want ? You want to get a string in the pair of [] after "result" ?

Comment: @HuryShen I dont want the two extra levels in my JSON you can see in my question I specified exactly the output I am trying to get, without the additional two levels that I dont know where they are coming from

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand your question, but I think the problem maybe in "OkObjectResult". Could you please share some more details of "OkObjectResult"

Comment: @HuryShen its a built in method its nothing I created

Comment: I test it in my side, you can replace the "ActionResult<JObject>" with "IActionResult" in your code. Please have a try~

Comment: @HuryShen that worked, I don’t understand why but it worked

Comment: Hi @MattDouhan , I post the solution to the answer area. If it helps your problem, could you please mark this answer as "accepted", thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, we should replace the "ActionResult" with "IActionResult". It's a problem caused by code design, we can also use "ActionResult" and without "".